# remove action from AMP plugin

Tags: filters

I'm trying to remove an action added by AMP plugin

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_hooks' );
function remove_hooks(){
  remove_action('wp_head', 'amp_frontend_add_canonical');
}
```

The plugin adds the action like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'amp_frontend_add_canonical' );

function amp_frontend_add_canonical() {
    if ( false === apply_filters( 'amp_frontend_show_canonical', true ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $amp_url = amp_get_permalink( get_queried_object_id() );

    printf( '<link rel="amphtml" href="%s" />', esc_url( $amp_url ) );
}
```

but I don't succeed - I'm not sure if I have to set a priority ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by changing to

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_hooks' );

function remove_hooks(){
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $format = get_post_format( $postid );

    if ($format == 'gallery') {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'amp_frontend_add_canonical',10);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will work, but a more proper place to hook your action on is on `template_redirect` which is "called" just before wordpress load template files. `p_enqueue_scripts` is actually called from inside of the `wp_head` action which makes his code a little shaky.